# Hide div contains a certain text then hide another div option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to figure out how I can hide a shipping option so that customers won't be able to see and select if one of the courier options includes the wording "Courier Rural"

Summary.

Hide Courier **DIV** (including the shippingprice) option IF Courier Rural **DIV** exists.

Example

```
<div class="shippingmethodlist">
     <div class="shippingmethod" id="trShippingMethod_1">
        <span id="tdShippingTitle_1" class="shippingmethodname">
          <label class="shippingmethod-label" >Courier</label>
        </span>
        <span class="shippingprice">
          <span id="tdShippingPrice_1">$0.00</span>
        </span>
     </div>
     <div class="shippingmethod" id="trShippingMethod_2">
        <span id="tdShippingTitle_2" class="shippingmethodname">
          <label class="shippingmethod-label" >Pick up in store</label>
        </span>
        <span class="shippingprice">
          <span id="tdShippingPrice_1">$0.00</span>
        </span>
     </div>
     <div class="shippingmethod" id="trShippingMethod_3">
        <span id="tdShippingTitle_3" class="shippingmethodname">
          <label class="shippingmethod-label" >Courier Rural</label>
        </span
        <span class="shippingprice">
          <span id="tdShippingPrice_1">$0.00</span>
        </span>
     </div>
</div>


jq(function () {
 if (jq(".shippingmethod-label").text() == "Courier Rural") {
     jq(".shippingmethod-label").text() == "Courier").hide();
 }
});
```

**EDIT: Let me just clarify that i want the whole div hidden, not just the label**

Comment: Can you explain what element should hide? The DIV? the LABEL?..

Comment: Hi @RokoC.Buljan yes would want to hide the div eg 

<div class="shippingmethod" id="trShippingMethod_1">
        <label class="shippingmethod-label" >Courier</label>
     </div>

Comment: See my answer below, I believe it is what you are looking for and have verified it is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is a "Courier Rural" label, iterate over elements with the `.shippingmethod-label` class and hide its parent if the text is equal to "Courier"

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($(".shippingmethod-label:contains('Courier Rural')").size()) {
    $(".shippingmethod-label").each(function() {
      if ($(this).html() === "Courier") {
        $(this).parent().parent().hide();
      }
    });
  }
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/18hzzb84/6/)

Comment: thanks for this, but i'm wanting to hide the "Courier" option ONLY if "Courier Rural" is shown.

Comment: Oh, I updated my answer and the fiddle. Please try now.

Comment: this worked but i forgot to include another div that is not the parent that needs to be hidden span (.shippingprice). Please scroll up for the html mark up

Comment: Since both the label and the span have the same parent, the .shippingprice span will not be displayed either. I updated the fiddle again to show you.

Comment: I see how it worked on Fiddle but didn't then i realized that the shipping label was wrapped inside another span div and that the shipping price was on its own separate span div. Sorry for this. Please look at my mark up again. Thank you

Comment: Just call parent() one more time before hiding. Updated code and fiddle.

Comment: Hi @yberg i was hoping you could assist me once more on this. If there was another shipping option how would I add onto the current working script you've provided? eg 

1. If "Courier"(show) then "Courier Rural"(hide) + "Courier Auckland"(hide). 2. If "Courier Auckland"(show) then "Courier"(hide) + "Courier Rural"(hide). 3. if "Courier Rural"(show) then "Courier"(hide) + "Courier Auckland"(hide)?

Comment: Just add two similar if statements and hide more stuff inside.
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/18hzzb84/10/)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure which div you need to hide but try

```
if ($('.shippingmethod-label:contains("Courier Rural")')) {
    $('.shippingmethodlist').find('.shippingmethod-label:contains("Courier")').hide();
}
```

Comment: Updated answer based on what I think you're after.

Answer (score 0):

This is a great use case for data attributes.  Add an attribute to each of your divs that looks something like this:

```
<div class="shippingmethod" data-purpose="something"></div>

<div class="shippingmethod" data-purpose="somethingelse"></div>
```

Then you can use the data attribute like you were the label selector in your JS function.

```
jq(function () {
    jq('.shippingmethod[data-purpose="something"]').hide();
});
```

**EDIT (based on comment by OP)**

If you cannot change the template html, and you MUST look for the element inside of the div, then you can use the [.parent()](https://api.jquery.com/parent/) function.

```
jq(function () {
    var courierOption, hideIt;
    jq('.shippingmethod-label').each(function(index, element) {
        if (element.text() === 'Courier Rural') {
            hideIt = true;
        } else if (element.text() === 'Courier') {
            courierOption = element.parent();
        }
    });

    if (hideIt) {
        courierOption.hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: Because it's a templated system, i can't go into the html file and adjust so have to use jquery

Comment: @Jc0807 please see my latest edit for a working solution.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you want to hide a different shipping option (let's say "Courier") if the option "Courier Rural" is present.

This is possible. You could do something like this:

```
var hideMe;
var shouldHide = false;

$(".shippingmethod-label").each(function() {
  var el = $(this);
  if (el.text() === "Courier") {
    hideMe = el;
  } else if (el.text() === "Courier Rural") {
    shouldHide = true;
  }
});

if (hideMe && shouldHide) {
  hideMe.hide(); // or hideMe.parent().hide(); based on your needs
}
```

However, if this is for a real site and not just a thought experiment, this should be handled on your back end.